# Wrong query generated in Rails 4 with has_many relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm developing a rails application with a legacy database, so I can not respect the conventions.
I have two models:

```
class Afiliado < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.primary_key = "idAfiliado"

  has_many :registros_odontologicos, 
           class_name: :RegistroOdontologico, 
           foreign_key: 'idRegistroOdontologico'
end


class RegistroOdontologico < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = "registrosodontologicos"
  self.primary_key = "idRegistroOdontologico"

  belongs_to :_afiliado, class_name: "Afiliado", foreign_key: "afiliado" 
end
```

When I call: `Afiliado.find(145).registros_odontologicos` Rails generates the query:

```
 Afiliado Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `afiliados`.* FROM `afiliados` WHERE `afiliados`.`idAfiliado` = 145 LIMIT 1
  RegistroOdontologico Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `registrosodontologicos`.* FROM `registrosodontologicos` WHERE `registr
osodontologicos`.`idRegistroOdontologico` = 145
```

I get an empty result but note that the last query is wrog. The query should be:

```
  SELECT `registrosodontologicos`.* FROM `registrosodontologicos` WHERE `registrosodontologicos`.`afiliado` = 145
```

What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE**
The reverse navegability works fine!

```
RegistroOdontologico.find(2)._afiliado
```

Generates:

```
  RegistroOdontologico Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `registrosodontologicos`.* FROM `registrosodontologicos` WHERE `registrosodontologicos`.`idRegistroOdontologico` = 2 LIMIT 1
  Afiliado Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `afiliados`.* FROM `afiliados` WHERE `afiliados`.`idAfiliado` = 145 ORDER BY `afiliados`.`idAfiliado` ASC LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an error in your configuration:

```
has_many :registros_odontologicos, class_name: :RegistroOdontologico, foreign_key: 'idRegistroOdontologico'
belongs_to :_afiliado, class_name: "Afiliado", foreign_key: "afiliado"
```

the `foreign_key` option is inconsistent.

Comment: Yes! `foreign_key` option in `has_many` must be  `foreign_key: 'afiliado'`. Thank you!!!!